# Convert wav data to flac data using JS

Tags: javascript, django, audio

I have a JS blob of WAV Data which I need to convert to FLAC data which I need to send an AJAX request to my localhost Django server where I want to use the Google Speech API.

The important thing here is that I don't want to store any kind of audio data anywhere on the server (So I think I should refrain from using commands which include "input.wav" and "output.flac")
I tried using [pySoX](https://github.com/rabitt/pysox) but didn't know how to use without providing the paths of input and output files.

I am open to any other strategies as I don't know how this is done conventionally.

Comment: There is flac.js but I don't know how to use it https://github.com/audiocogs/flac.js

Comment: Yeah, I was aware of it but wasn't able to find any examples of it.